# ¿Cómo puedo agrupar ítems de un Json?

Tags: php, json

Quisiera agrupar items de un json. Me explico a continuación debajo

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "cliente": "manu",
        "poblacion": "barcelona"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "cliente": "Jose",
        "poblacion": "madrid"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "cliente":  "David",
        "poblacion":"barcelona"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "cliente":  "ramon",
        "poblacion": "Valencia"
    }
]
```

y me gustaría agruparlos por población. ¿Cómo se puede hacer? Con while y foreach no hay manera. Este es mi código hasta ahora

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT  * FROM obras");

while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $rows[] = $row;
}

foreach($rows as $row){
    echo $row['poblacion'];
}
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a ordenarlos o a obtener algún tipo de total? ¿Por qué no lo haces directamente en SQL?

Comment: Muestra un ejemplo de cómo debería quedar le JSON que esperas obtener, indica también tu versión de MySQL, pues las versiones modernas incorporan funciones y tipos de datos específicos para JSON. Como bien indica @DavidJP, la mejor opción para este caso será obtener la estructura que quieres directamente desde la consulta SQL (mediante funciones propias de JSON si tu versión de MySQL las soporta, o con `CONCAT`, `GROUP_CONCAT` y `GROUP_BY`), no teniendo luego que manipular los datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que

```
$json = json_decode('[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "cliente": "manu",
        "poblacion": "barcelona"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "cliente": "Jose",
        "poblacion": "madrid"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "cliente":  "David",
        "poblacion":"barcelona"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "cliente":  "ramon",
        "poblacion": "Valencia"
    }
]');
```

Creamos un array para agrupar

```
$agrupar=[];
```

Recorremos el `json`

```php
foreach($json as $k => $v){
  $agrupar[$v->poblacion][]=$v;
}
```

**Resultado**

```php
array (size=3)
  'barcelona' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[1]
          public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'cliente' => string 'manu' (length=4)
          public 'poblacion' => string 'barcelona' (length=9)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[3]
          public 'id' => string '3' (length=1)
          public 'cliente' => string 'David' (length=5)
          public 'poblacion' => string 'barcelona' (length=9)
  'madrid' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[2]
          public 'id' => string '2' (length=1)
          public 'cliente' => string 'Jose' (length=4)
          public 'poblacion' => string 'madrid' (length=6)
  'Valencia' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[4]
          public 'id' => string '4' (length=1)
          public 'cliente' => string 'ramon' (length=5)
          public 'poblacion' => string 'Valencia' (length=8)
```

Comment: Eso es! Mil gracias @wilfredo